# This web container has not yet been started in Glassfish while deploying ADF app

Tags: glassfish, oracle-adf, glassfish-4

I am not able to re-deploy my ADF application in glassfish. I am getting the exception "This web container has not yet been started". I have removed the old application. Also. I have restarted the domain. But the error still persists.

I have tried almost everything. Also checked related queries inside the stack overflow. If suspect the issue is of EntityManagerFactor. But not sure.

I am deploying Oracle ADF application and I am using Oracle Database. Also, Sample application was already deployed in the server. But after some changes in the coding. I am not able to do so.

```
    [2019-01-27T12:18:15.439+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [AS-NAMING-00006] [org.glassfish.naming] [tid: _ThreadID=2414 _ThreadName=DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] [timeMillis: 1548580695439] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception in NamingManagerImpl copyMutableObject(): {0}
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl$OSGiObjectInputStream.resolveClass(OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl.java:161)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl$1.run(NamingUtilsImpl.java:125)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl.makeCopyOfObject(NamingUtilsImpl.java:123)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:147)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at ei.util.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:38)
        at ei.integration.generic.ap.APLoadDataScheduler.executeAPLoadScheduler(APLoadDataScheduler.java:55)
        at ei.integration.generic.ap.APLoadDataScheduler.execute(APLoadDataScheduler.java:40)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
    ]]

    [2019-01-27T12:18:15.440+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=2414 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1548580695440] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Cant copy Serializable object:]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:513)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at ei.util.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:38)
        at ei.integration.generic.ap.APLoadDataScheduler.executeAPLoadScheduler(APLoadDataScheduler.java:55)
        at ei.integration.generic.ap.APLoadDataScheduler.execute(APLoadDataScheduler.java:40)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cant copy Serializable object:
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl.makeCopyOfObject(NamingUtilsImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:147)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl$OSGiObjectInputStream.resolveClass(OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl.java:161)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl$1.run(NamingUtilsImpl.java:125)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl.makeCopyOfObject(NamingUtilsImpl.java:123)
        ... 10 more]]

    [2019-01-27T12:18:15.440+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=2414 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1548580695440] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      java.lang.NullPointerException]]

    [2019-01-27T12:18:15.440+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=2414 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1548580695440] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      java.lang.NullPointerException]]

    [2019-01-27T12:18:15.440+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=2414 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1548580695440] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      java.lang.NullPointerException]]

    [2019-01-27T12:18:21.003+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [AS-NAMING-00006] [org.glassfish.naming] [tid: _ThreadID=2408 _ThreadName=DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] [timeMillis: 1548580701003] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception in NamingManagerImpl copyMutableObject(): {0}
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl$OSGiObjectInputStream.resolveClass(OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl.java:161)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl$1.run(NamingUtilsImpl.java:125)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl.makeCopyOfObject(NamingUtilsImpl.java:123)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:147)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at ei.util.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:38)
        at ei.integration.generic.scheduler.PartyLoadDataScheduler.executePartyLoadScheduler(PartyLoadDataScheduler.java:52)
        at ei.integration.generic.scheduler.PartyLoadDataScheduler.execute(PartyLoadDataScheduler.java:40)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
    ]]

    [2019-01-27T12:18:21.005+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=2408 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1548580701005] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Cant copy Serializable object:]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:513)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at ei.util.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:38)
        at ei.integration.generic.scheduler.PartyLoadDataScheduler.executePartyLoadScheduler(PartyLoadDataScheduler.java:52)
        at ei.integration.generic.scheduler.PartyLoadDataScheduler.execute(PartyLoadDataScheduler.java:40)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cant copy Serializable object:
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl.makeCopyOfObject(NamingUtilsImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:147)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithLoader.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.common.util.OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl$OSGiObjectInputStream.resolveClass(OSGiObjectInputOutputStreamFactoryImpl.java:161)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl$1.run(NamingUtilsImpl.java:125)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.NamingUtilsImpl.makeCopyOfObject(NamingUtilsImpl.java:123)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still don't know what was the issue. But I have stoped the server then manually deleted the folder of my application insde the "..glassfish\domains\domain1\applications" folder. And started the server. And tried to deploy my application. And it was deployed successfully this time.

Comment: I've deleted applications folder. Nothing has changed. BUT :)) When I restored the applications folder the poblem solved. weird but works. :D